# Replace top link navigation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, development, master-page, top-link-bar

What it is the recommended way to replace the "top link navigation" by hardcoded links? (in SharePoint 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find below mentioned tags in SharePoint master page

```
<div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks">
```

please don't touch the code in-between these two tags.
Put `style="display:none;"` to that `DIV` tag like below.

```
<div class="s4-lp s4-toplinks" style="display:none;">
```

Put your static menu code above the hidden html `DIV` tag

**E.g.**

Here is the sample code for top HTML navigation & Don't forget to attach CSS file for your Top Navigation within the master page.

```
<div class="navbar-header left-navbar">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="left-navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".left-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" id="left-navbar-brand" href="#">Left Menu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot find this tags in masterpage. This is 2010?

Comment: yes this is SP 2010

Comment: Wicht master page are you using?

Comment: I have updated my answer as i had copied the content from my custom master page.

Comment: Is that working for you? as i had tried the same using SharePoint Designer in my 'v4.master'